# How to make TR/TD immovable in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have table with several number of tds and trs. Some of my tr have styling(change background color and change font style to bold etc.) on hovering. The issue am facing is when I mouse over/hover the fields are styling as expected, but the td/tr columns moving or shaking because of that styling. Is there anyway to prevent that from occurring? Thanks in advance.

The following is my css,

```
.customCHTR:hover
{
  border: red;
  background-color:#e7e7e7;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: give the tds some max-height/max-width to keep the box the sdame size upon hover. or just don't use bold,use color/underline/outline/box-shadow, which doesn't cause reflow...

Comment: do you have border?i think it just an effect of removing the border so it looks like its moving

Comment: try providing some demo so it is easy to understand and view the issue, this helps in solving the problem

Answer (score 1):

It's important to define the td's border size and keep it the same when it hovers. Also you should add a width property to the td. That should solve your issue.

```
td {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
}

.customCHTR:hover {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelwagner/m95t1ouL/) so you can see it in action. Hope that helps.

Comment: That example does not work properly, the td still grows bigger because of the text-bold on hover, which causes to increase the height of the cell. The OP should use a specified cell height.

Comment: Catch22, yeah some thing like that, nearly there. Thanks :)

Comment: But I heard there is some styling like fixed or something?

Comment: @Tirzono As far as I can tell, the td does not grow at all. I assumed that on hover the OP wanted the text to go bold which, of course would increase it's size. The shaking that was originally described is no longer apparent, but if the OP wants the text not to increase in size, then they need to keep the font-weight the same.

Comment: @vellattukudy Yes there is a fixed position property but I don't think that's what you want here because that takes the elements out of the documents flow and fixes it to the window instead. If you're truly concered about the bold font changing its size, try adding font-family: monospace; to the table.